# Virtual user persisting Roles after logout

Tags: authentication, user-management, context-user

I am trying to login a virtual user for my application and have assigned roles to this virtual user.

```
var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, true);
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role itemRole = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName(role.ToLower());
virtualUser.Roles.Add(itemRole);
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(virtualUser);
```

Now I want to logout from this Virtual User so I have used

```
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout();
```

It works fine until here.. but when I login to this virtual user again. It persists the roles that were previously assigned to it.
how can I remove assigned roles from the virtual user before I log the user out?
I have tried removing all roles before logout but that didn't work.

```
Sitecore.Context.User.Roles.RemoveAll();
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout()
```

Other approaches I have tried which didn't work.

```
var virtualuser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser();
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout();
virtualUser.Delete();
```

and

```
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
```

What should be done to remove roles and logout the virtual user?

**Update**: I am using `extranet\authenticated` as the username to login as a virtual user. Could this be causing the issue.
`Sitecore Version 9.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by adding below code.

```
            var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser();
            virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Clear();
            virtualUser.Roles.RemoveAll();
            virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.Save();
            Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout();
```

Apparently VirtualUser properties and roles are stored in `ClientData` table which does not clear added roles until you use `virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.Save()` to update the `ClientData` table.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore does not clear virtual users after logout. To over come this, you can remove the virtual user roles before logout

```
var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser();
```

// Remove roles here from virtualUser

```
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout(); virtualUser.User.Delete();
```

Comment: what is ```VirtualUser``` in this case?

Comment: Updates the answer

Comment: I was not able to find ```virtualUser.Logout()```. I tried ```virtualUser.Delete()``` but that didn't work.

Comment: @Shaurya did this work for you? You should still use the call `Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout()` to logout.

Comment: @Shaurya I don't have access to the code base to give you exact code, but you can try the following, Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout();
virtualUser.User.Delete();

Comment: @JuliusAI called the ```AuthenticationManager.Logout()``` but that didn't work as well. 
@MaheshRaghupathi: I have updated the question with the methods I had tried until now. i seem to be missing something.

Comment: @Shaurya this this, var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser(); virtualUSer.Roles.RemoveAll();
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout()